# How to find the current age of a star as a function of its luminosity

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, astronomy, stellar-evolution, star-clusters

In my recent research, I have found the need to find an age of a star. But instead, I have found information telling me on how to calculate the age of a star cluster. Hence I wonder is there a formula that gives the current or an estimate of a star age, given its luminosity as it is the amount of energy being released in a given period.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to determine the age of start all by itself, because many stars(star cluster) will have same start time but due to composition, the age varies i.e., the mass or magnitude determines the actual age.

The simple way to understand the current age is through the HR diagram.

refer these links,

1. https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.5237 is paper work.
2. http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/H/Hertzsprung-Russell+Diagram reference for HR diagram.
3. https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-scientists-determi/

Comment: For posterity's sake (i.e. in case of eventual link rot), could a short summary be added of how one would determine this via HR diagram?